# when i try to get a non-unique list i somehow get a empty list

Tags: python, list

I'm self-teach python, and when i try to slove one of the questions in Empire of Code, there is a problem i somehow can't figure out what's the problem.

Question:

```
def non_unique(data):
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert isinstance(non_unique([1]), list), "The result must be a list"
    assert non_unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3], "1st example"
    assert non_unique([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [], "2nd example"
    assert non_unique([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], "3rd example"
    assert non_unique([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9], "4th example"
```

My Solution:

```
def non_unique(data):
    a = data
    for i in data:
        if data.count(i) == 1:
            b = [data.remove(i)]
            print(i)
            if b == [None]:
                b = []
        else:
            b = a
    return b
```

Problem: Some list i can get the right result, but some other i somehow get the empty list, that really confused me

Comment: what is the question though? What is the task? Keep all list items that appear more than once?

Comment: What's the meaning of your `non_unique` function? To filter out duplicates from a passed list?

Comment: @zwer Probably to filter out **non-duplicates** from the passed list

Comment: You're removing from a list while iterating, don't do that, make a new list like `[item for item in data if data.count(item) > 1]` or use `collections.Counter`

Comment: @Chirs_Rands Thx, it's useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not-very-efficient way of getting what you want (which I'm inferring is a list that only includes duplicate objects in `data`):

```
def non_unique(data):
    return [d for d in data if data.count(d) > 1]
```

The reason your code isn't working is because `data.remove(i)` *always* returns `None`, so your `if b == [None]` condition is always `True`, and thus `b` is always set to an empty list.  Also, for each iteration over the items in `data`, you're reassigning the value of `b`, so your return value will only be the *last* value that `b` was assigned to in the `for` loop.  If the final item in `data` was in fact a duplicate, it should return the correct answer, but if the final item is not a duplicate, it will always return an empty list.

Comment: really appreciate the answer, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I would do it:

```
def non_unique(data):
    temp = [sub[0] for sub in [(item, data.count(item)) for item in set(data)] if sub[1] > 1]
    return [i for i in data if i in temp]
```

---

Explanation:

`[(item, data.count(item)) for item in set(data)]`:
Data is converted to a set to get the unique values and count the number of appearances for each. It returns a tuple which in the *index-1* position contains the count.

`[sub[0] for sub in [..] if sub[1] > 1]`:
For all items that have a count > 1 get the item *index-0* from the tuple contained in the inner list.

`[i for i in data if i in temp]`:
Finally to preserve the order of the original list iterate through it and keep everything that was *distilled* previously.

---

NOTE

This solution is more effective than simply doing `[d for d in data if data.count(d) > 1]` because this variation gets the `count` of every duplicate multiple times.

---

ASSERTIONS:

```
assert isinstance(non_unique([1]), list), "The result must be a list"
assert non_unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3], "1st example"
assert non_unique([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [], "2nd example"
assert non_unique([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], "3rd example"
assert non_unique([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9], "4th example"
```

They all run without raising `AssertionError`

Comment: You raise a good point with your note, but I prefer a counter, like `c = collections.Counter(data); [x for x in data if c[x] > 1]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands You had a comment on that so I was kind of expecting you to go forth with the `.Counter()`. But yeah, that looks less intimidating than the double list-comprehension. I guess they are equivalent in terms of algorithms but `counter` might be faster if implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink how you are structuring your solution. The `.remove` list method removes the first occurrence of that value in the list.

```
>>> a = [1,3,4]
>>> a.remove(1)
>>> a
[3, 4]
```

It will always return None, or raise an error if trying to remove a value that doesn't exist.

Your function will return weird things because it's returning `b`, which is sometimes `a` (which in turn is `data`, which is also being mutated with `.remove`), and sometimes an empty list from the `b = []` line.

I would suggest setting up something like: (in pseudocode):

```
answer = []
for value in data:
    if data has only one occurrence of value:
        add value to the answer list

return answer
```

This is a good case where, instead of removing from the original data, you should be building a new set of data. (ie. building a new list and returning that rather than mutating the original data).

EDIT: this idea of building a new (filtered) set of data is the idea behind the list comprehension techniques given in other answers here.